# How to extract only data matching string in Xpath

Tags: xpath

When Xpath expression is applied on */data/title* , the results displayed are 'All the connections', 'Forward Details', 'Forward Detail',''Forward Detail', 'Forward Details' , 'ABCD', ...e.t.c..

My xpath expression has to list only if the /title is 'Forward Detail' or ''Forward Details'...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<title>All the connections</title>
<List>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P9909</Price>
    </Listitem>
</List>
<title>Forward Detail</title>
<List>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P45</Price>
    </Listitem>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P98</Price>
    </Listitem>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P68</Price>
    </Listitem>
</List>
<title>Forward Details</title>
<List>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P452</Price>
    </Listitem>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P983</Price>
    </Listitem>
</List>
<title>Forward Detail</title>
<List>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P4501</Price>
    </Listitem>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P909</Price>
    </Listitem>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P899</Price>
    </Listitem>
</List>
<title>Forward Details</title>
<List>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P4522</Price>
    </Listitem>
    <Listitem>
        <Price>P98311</Price>
    </Listitem>
</List>
```

of this input, I have to extract the price of only 'Forward Detail' and 'Forward Details'. I have to ignore the rest.

Please help me in framing the Xpath for this. I am using Xpath 1.0

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 3):

Try if next command works for you:

```
/data/title[text() = "Forward Detail" or text() = "Forward Details"]/following-sibling::*[1]/descendant::Price
```

My result:

```
<Price>P45</Price>
<Price>P98</Price>
<Price>P68</Price>
<Price>P452</Price>
<Price>P983</Price>
<Price>P4501</Price>
<Price>P909</Price>
<Price>P899</Price>
<Price>P4522</Price>
<Price>P98311</Price>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a condition. Something like `/data/title[text() == 'Forward Detail']`.

However I suspect you actually need the List that is preceded by given title, right? Your XML is badly designed for that (it should have the title *inside* the `<List>` element instead), but XPath is capable enough to cope. You need to look at the `sibling` axis and the `pos()` function.

I'd have to look in the documentation myself, so I am just making this a community wiki; anybody feel free to rewrite.

Comment: yes Jan.. the xml is badly shaped and being a huge file, and need to extract few data.. I got the condition right.. but not able to extract the required info..

Comment: @Ramm: See Birei's answer. It's full version of what I had in mind.